# Recyclerview.notifyItemInserted() duplicates the list item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement, where I should download the ad item while scrolling and update the list. Since calling `notifyDatasetChnaged()`, resets everything, I'm calling `notifyItemInserted(position)`. But, calling this duplicated the items in the list. I found that there are no repeated items in the list. But after calling `notifyItemInserted`, it duplicates the item. I'm not getting how to resolve this issue. This what I'm doing:

```
mNewsList.add(mPreviousAdPosition, newsItem);
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mPreviousAdPosition);
```

If I call, it works properly, there are no repeated items. But I don't want my list items to recreate. What can be the issue ?

Comment: what is previousAdPosition here?

Comment: previousAdPostion is taken from feed. We insert the ad at this position

Comment: mNewsList.add(mPreviousAdPosition, newsItem);
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mPreviousAdPosition);
where do you put those line ?

Comment: After ad is downloaded, i insert the ad item in the list and then notifying the adapter

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for exactly the same use case, the solution is:

Implement this method in your Adapter :

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    //Return the stable ID for the item at position
    return items.get(position).getId();
}
```

Call this method in the Constructor of your Adapter :

```
//Indicates whether each item in the data set can be represented with a unique identifier
setHasStableIds(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the object at the end of the array with each object having a position along with it where it needs to be shown  in the recycler view. Sort this array on the basis of position before calling `notifyItemInserted(position)`. In this way only required data will be drawn.I have recenlty followed this approach and works very well with dynamic sections added in between in recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the item at the end of the list.

```
mNewsList.add(newsItem);
```

and then notify like this.

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mNewsList.size()-1);
```

Comment: But I want to add the item in between? It will not for such cases ?

Comment: In your code remove the view before calling notifyItemInserted. Ex - yourlistview.removeViewAt(mPreviousAdPosition);

Comment: But I have a big list and I want all items in the list. So, the item where ad will be inserted must come below the inserted item position.

Answer (score 0):

You code should be written like this:

```
  public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

   ...

   public void addData(int position, Item newsItem) {

        mNewsList.add(position, newsItem);

        notifyItemInserted(position);

   }

   ...

 }
```

and then you need to call the fun `addData`

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary list and add items as mentioned below:

```
List<YourModel> mTmpList = new ArrayList<YourMdel>();

//add items (from 0 -> mPreviousAdPosition) to mTmpList;
for(int i=0; i<mPreviousAdPosition; i++) {
    mTmpList.add(mNewsList.get(i));
}

//add item at mPreviousAdPosition
mTmpList.add(newsItem);

//add remaining items and set i<=mNewsList.size() because we ha
for(int i=mPreviousAdPosition; i<=mNewsList.size(); i++) {
    mTmpList.add(mNewsList.get(i - 1)); //because we have added item at mPreviousAdPosition;
}

mNewsList = mTmpList;
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```